# CardCornerRadius in cardview looking weird in android Pie

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-9.0-pie

My CardView was being shown as expected till **android O** like this,

[image]

But in **android P** it looks like this, *(Transparent white rectangle inside)*

[image]

This is the style used in all CardView of the app.

```
 <style name="translucentCard" parent="CardView">
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">20dp</item>
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#26ffffff</item>
 </style>
```

If I use non-transparent `cardBackgroundColor` then the inner rectangle disappears but it's not the solution. I need to use semi-transparent color as used before. Can anyone help me to overcome this please ? Please note, It's only happening in **Android Pie**.

Comment: can you put your xml code ?

Comment: @sandeepkolhal Simply `style` attribute is written in  `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`. I think there is nothing more relevant in further layout xml file.

Comment: I think you have used linear or relative layout in cardview. If you have used any parent layout make background transparent and try.

Comment: Yeah it is. It's the child element of `LinearLayout`. I've tried making the parent layout 100% transparent too. But no luck. It's only happening in android P.

Comment: put your xml so I can help you

Comment: @sandeepkolhal Added. `@style/paddedContainer` has 4 paddings and nothing more.. I tried removing it too. So lets not put effort to this.

Comment: try cardView's contentPadding instead of regular padding

Comment: @TimCastelijns padding isn't used in cardview.. Do I have to use contentPadding in LinearLayout inside cardview ?

Comment: Are you using any custom components related to this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

backward compatible elevation on the latest release

```
app:cardElevation="0dp"
```

OR

```
<item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
```

Comment: What if I want to retain CardView's elevation?

Answer (score 0):

Use This hope this will work :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="...">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="..." />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/translucentCard"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/paddedContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_email">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/.."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="8dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_password">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPasswordForLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="8dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
        style="@style/WarrentyLifeTheme.TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_forgot_password" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="36dp"
        android:paddingRight="36dp"
        android:text="@string/dashboard_button_login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added android:background="@android:color/transparent" in your linear layout

Comment: no luck bro. It didn't work.. May be something is wrong in android P Beta program. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
android:background="@null"
```

to LinearLayout inside the CardView or to TextViews inside this LinearLayout.

This way you will remove the background altogether so there won't be any overdraw.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this**

```
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorGray"
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorGray"
```

> This solved my problem. Use gray color with a low transparency